# how to make it can shows the calculation process?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, process, calculation

```
n =78
def subtracts_sum(n):
    sum = 0
    while n > 0:
        number = n%10
        sum = sum+number
        n = int(n/10)
    return sum    
subtracts_sum(n)
n - subtracts_sum(n)
```

This is what I wrote, and the output is 63. However, I want to make it have a calculation process, like 78-(7+8) = 63. Can somebody help me? thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Is this function only for 2 digit numbers ? Does it support "n" digit numbers ?

Comment: I think it can uses more than 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on it like a string, in python every string works like a list, and you can call any parts of the string by using a[x:y:z]

Just follow the code and you're good to go

```
def subtracts_sum(n):
    sum = 0
    while n > 0:
        number = n%10
        sum = sum+number
        n = int(n/10)
    return sum  

n =78

print(f'{n}-(',end='')

for i in str(n)[:-1:] :
    print(f'{i}+',end='')
print(str(n)[-1::],end='')
print(f')={n - subtracts_sum(n)}')
```